# Select every first array value in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, dimension

I dynamically create this associative file array through a PHP script, and now I am wondering how do I select all values inside the root array?
I'll explain here in code.

This is the array that is currently getting generated everytime:

```
Array
(
    [HTML] => Array
        (
            [0] => Index.php
        )

[Javascript] => Array
    (
        [0] => Javascript.js
        [1] => Jquery.js
    )

[0] => New Text Document.txt
[Scripts] => Array
    (
        [0] => Get_Server_files.Script.php
    )

[Style] => Array
    (
        [0] => General.css
        [1] => Menu.css
        [2] => Style.css
    )

[images] => Array
    (
        [WelcomeImages] => Array
            (
                [0] => WelcomeImage0.png
                [1] => WelcomeImage1.png
                [2] => WelcomeImage2.png
                [3] => WelcomeImage3.png
                [4] => WelcomeImage4.png
                [5] => WelcomeImage5.png
                [6] => WelcomeImage6.png
            )

        [0] => bg.jpg
    )

)
```

From here, how do I select every first value? As in selecting

- HTML
- Javascript
- Scripts
- Style
- Images.

And not anything that is inside these arrays.

I have searched but everytime it's not quite what I would like.

Comment: Do you mean the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/array_keys) to get the names and then use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) to remove the `0` values:

```
$names = array_filter(array_keys($data));
print_r($names);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTML
    [1] => Javascript
    [3] => Scripts
    [4] => Style
    [5] => images
)
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/81492)

Comment: Thank you very much, the answer had already been given. It's both near the same, although i prefer johns answer since it is shorter. But thank you very much!

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg: No worries. If you use just `array_keys()`, you'll get an extra `0` in the resulting array. [See demo](https://eval.in/81493). I'm using `array_filter()` to remove that.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_keys()`](http://www.php.net/array_keys)

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, So stupid. My biggest problems always turn out to be the easiest solutions. Thank you very much though!